# creating reactive array session storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to exclude documents to show on `client` based on user event.

this is my attempt which failed:

```
Template.documents.events({
  'click #dontShowThisDocument': function () {
    Session.set('excludedDocument', this._id);
  }
});

Template.documents.helpers({
  lists: function () {
    var excludedDocuments = [];
    excludedDocuments.push(Session.get('excludedDocument'));
    return Coll.find({_id:{$nin:excludedDocuments});
  }
});
```

how to create `array` session storage with `meteor` so then the user able to exclude certain document on a list `reactively` ?

Thank You so much.

Comment: Do you mean `Session.get('excludedDocument')`?

Comment: helloo @DavidWeldon thanks for your response.. yapp i'm trying to push every `Session.get('excludedDocument')` to array `excludedDocuments`... apologize i don't understand your question,,

Comment: @KarinaL The code above does not include quotes around `excludedDocument` when calling `Session.get`. I don't know if that's a typo you made when asking the question, or if it's in your code and throwing an error.  Either way that looks suspect.

Comment: Can you describe _how_ your attempt failed? As I read it right now you are instantiating a new array each time, which is odd. If you want to have only one array into which you push values as they are selected, you should hoist the declaration in the scope above.

Comment: @Kyll the list isn't update...the document that should exclude still persist in a list,,,

Comment: Your code looks okay then (you could use `$ne` instead of `$nin` though). Could you post the template code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Session variable can hold an array (or any object really) which means you could do this:

```
Template.documents.events({
  'click #dontShowThisDocument': function () {
    var excluded = Session.get('excludedDocument');
    if ( excluded ) excluded.push(this._id);
    else excluded = [ this.id ];
    Session.set('excludedDocument',excluded);
  }
});

Template.documents.helpers({
  lists: function () {
    return Coll.find({ _id: { $nin: Session.get('excludedDocument') });
  }
});
```